# DataTables! Unable to apply datatables when creating dynamic table with flask

Tags: jquery, flask, datatables

A table is made,but "datatables" are not applied.
Thank you.

python(3.5)

**html**

```
<select id="name" class="selectpicker" data-width="100px" title="시도">
      <option value='Tiger Nixon'>Tiger Nixon</option>
      <option value='Garrett Winters'>Garrett Winters</option>
      <option value='Ashton Cox'>Ashton Cox</option>
      <option value='Cedric Kelly'>Cedric Kelly</option>
      <option value='Airi Satou'>Airi Satou</option>
      <option value='Brielle Williamson'>Brielle Williamson</option>
</select>
<button id = "start" class="btn btn-primary " >View</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

**html**

**script**
Code sending value to flasks

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#start").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var selected_name= $("#name").val();
      $.post("/result" ,{
        name: selected_name
      }, function(resp) {
          $("#result").html(resp);
     });
  });
});

</script>
```

**script**
DatTables script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
</script>
```

**flask app**

```
@app.route("/")
def index() :
    return render_template("table.html")


@app.route("/result", methods=["POST"])
def result():
    data = [
[ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
[ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750" ],
[ "Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000" ],
[ "Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060" ],
[ "Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700" ],
[ "Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "4804", "2012/12/02", "$372,000" ]
]

df = DataFrame(data,columns = ['name','Position','Office','Extn.','Start date','Salary'])
name = request.form.get("name")
table = df.query('name == "{0}"'.format(name))
return table.to_html(classes='display" id ="example" width="100%')
```

Comment: Is your example table generated dynamically?

Comment: Yes, the tables are generated, but CSS and js are not applied. However, the static table applies to datatables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are not creating table using dataTable. You are appending content of the table using jquery which dataTable unaware of.

DataTable provides [inbuilt option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) to make ajax call. You have to change your code as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable(
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/result",
            "type": "POST",
            "data" : {
               name : selected_name
            }
        },
    );
});
```

---

In **html** you have to create table element so that dataTable will be able to find the table with given id or class and append data to that table.

```
<div id="result">
 <table id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Extn.</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
 </table>
</div>
```

---

In **flask app** you need not to change change the content into html format.

```
@app.route("/")
def index() :
    return render_template("table.html")


@app.route("/result", methods=["POST"])
def result():
    data = [
[ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
[ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750" ],
[ "Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000" ],
[ "Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060" ],
[ "Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700" ],
[ "Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "4804", "2012/12/02", "$372,000" ]
]

    # return the results as json # import json
    return json.dumps(data)
```

---

---

Besides this you can also do it other way round. Once you append the response in `#result` div, after that initialize dataTable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#start").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selected_name= $("#name").val();
    $.post("/result" ,{ name: selected_name}, function(resp) {
      $("#result").html(resp);
      // now initialize dataTable 
      $('#example').DataTable({
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "age" },
            { "data": "start_date" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ]
      }); 
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Css and Js work well. However, the above code does not work.

Comment: Make sure to send the query value from the flask to the json data\html.  lf you create a table first in html, the column name displays the column name. Thanks, but is there any other way?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand. Did you try above two solutions?

Comment: which one did you try and what problem did you face. Please provide proper information.

Comment: <div in="result"> tag retult(The result is the same.)     [["Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800"], ["Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750"], ["Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000"], ["Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060"], ["Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700"], ["Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "4804", "2012/12/02", "$372,000"]]

Comment: @ Prashant Pokhriyal It's my fault. It works well. thank you~